# What does importing with an asterisk do in react native?

Tags: react-native, import

When starting a project on snack.expo.io it defaults to

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

What is the difference between that and

```
import React from 'react';
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name parameter is the name of the "module object" which will be used as a kind of namespace to refer to the exports. The export parameters specify individual named exports, while the import * as name syntax imports all of them. Below are examples to clarify the syntax.

***Import an entire module's contents***

This inserts myModule into the current scope, containing all the exports from the module in the file located in /modules/my-module.js.

import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js';
Here, accessing the exports means using the module name ("myModule" in this case) as a namespace. For example, if the module imported above includes an export doAllTheAmazingThings(), you would call it like this:

**myModule.doAllTheAmazingThings();**

***Import a single export from a module***

Given an object or value named myExport which has been exported from the module my-module either implicitly (because the entire module is exported) or explicitly (using the export statement), this inserts myExport into the current scope.

import {myExport} from '/modules/my-module.js';

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does that have an impact on the performance of the app? Does it affect the bundled size or does compilation trim this down? As I develop my programming, I'd like to learn the better habits...

Comment: Not at all.. its all about like how you define a variable and call that... It doesn't make impact on it working for that